# Are all of unplugged people hackers?

Tags: the-matrix

Trinity and Neo were both hackers. Obviously Jax and the line operator's. It makes me curious if *The Matrix* is a tribute to the strength of hackers.

Comment: Also, the line operators were not necessarily hackers in the same way. Tank was a Zion born human,  not a red pill.

Answer (score 6):

No. There are many people who aren't hackers. Prime example comes from Animatrix stories "Kid's Story" where the character [Kid](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Kid), a normal teenage student, actually comes into the real movies, and "[World Record](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/World_Record)" where a world class athlete almost breaks out from [sheer physical prowess itself](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Self_substantiation) .

As the stories say, people with "a rare degree of intuition, sensitivity, and a questioning nature" are the ones who break out of the Matrix without help. Those traits are also common in hackers, but not exclusive to them.

Comment: In support of your answer, my impression of the Wachowskis is that they are more focused on the spiritual/psychological elements as opposed to the technical.